# Close dialog when click outside of it

Tags: c#, dialog, gtk#

I'm working with GTK# and I have a dialog that I want to close when user clicks out of it. Very similar to the way a combobox works: when the dropdown list is expanded and you click out of it, it closes.
There are similar questions to this problem, but for other languages =( and I can't figure out a way to relate those answers to my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should add more details to your question !

Answer (score 0):

At first guess, you should connect to the `notify::has-toplevel-focus` signal of your dialog, and close it when the `has-toplevel-focus` property becomes false.